# Doxygen Warning: ignoring unknown tag

Tags: c++, c++11, documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation

Using Doxygen to generate documentation. Getting "Warning: ignoring unknown tag" errors, and I can't see why.

**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:**

```
/** This is a test */
#include <iostream>

/** \fn foo */
int foo() {
    return 0;
}

int main() {   
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Errors:**

```
[53]: doxygen .\myTest.cpp
Warning: ignoring unknown tag `This' at line 1, file .\myTest.cpp
Warning: ignoring unknown tag `is' at line 1, file .\myTest.cpp
Warning: ignoring unknown tag `a' at line 1, file .\myTest.cpp
Warning: ignoring unknown tag `test' at line 1, file .\myTest.cpp
Warning: ignoring unknown tag `fn' at line 4, file .\myTest.cpp
Warning: ignoring unknown tag `foo' at line 4, file .\myTest.cpp
Warning: ignoring unknown tag `int' at line 5, file .\myTest.cpp
Warning: ignoring unknown tag `foo' at line 5, file .\myTest.cpp
Warning: ignoring unknown tag `return' at line 6, file .\myTest.cpp
Warning: ignoring unknown tag `0' at line 6, file .\myTest.cpp
Warning: ignoring unknown tag `int' at line 9, file .\myTest.cpp
Warning: ignoring unknown tag `main' at line 9, file .\myTest.cpp
Warning: ignoring unknown tag `std' at line 10, file .\myTest.cpp
Warning: ignoring unknown tag `cout' at line 10, file .\myTest.cpp
Warning: ignoring unknown tag `hello' at line 10, file .\myTest.cpp
Warning: ignoring unknown tag `world' at line 10, file .\myTest.cpp
Warning: ignoring unknown tag `std' at line 10, file .\myTest.cpp
Warning: ignoring unknown tag `endl' at line 10, file .\myTest.cpp
Warning: ignoring unknown tag `return' at line 11, file .\myTest.cpp
Warning: ignoring unknown tag `0' at line 11, file .\myTest.cpp
Searching for include files...
Searching for example files...
Searching for images...
Searching for dot files...
Searching for files to exclude
Searching for files to process...
...other stuff...
```

Thx, Sincerely, Keith :^)

Answer (score 4):

You're passing your file into doxygen as if it were the configuration file, and not a cpp. This is why it gives you an error on every word.

> To generate the documentation you can now enter:
>
> `doxygen <config-file>`

see http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/starting.html#step2

Instead, generate a config file next to your source:

```
doxygen -g myconfig.conf
```

And then run doxygen:

```
doxygen myconfig.conf
```

Which will default to building documentation from the files in your current directory, due to the default of `INPUT =`.